Supabase Storage API, How to use it in android studio java?
I'm developing a social platform app kinda like twitter in android studio. I'm using java cause I have experience with it. So the backend is supabase API using retrofit and http. I have done all the feature for the app now all I need is how to add picture as a profile image.
Supabase has this feature called storage, but idk how to use it and how to upload an image in android studio java. Can anyone help me on how to do it? or can anyone give me a tutorial video that specifically solve my problem?
